# xp_dirtree not giving correct results

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to fetch the list of files from a directory using xp_dirtree from below code:

```
EXEC xp_dirtree '/home/ejazah/Documents/share/wego/flights_daily_api_health_reports/', 1,1
```

It is working fine till yesterday and suddenly started giving files for which file value is 0 instead of 1.

```
subdirectory    depth    file
.%2E            1        0
```

This `.%2E` subdirectory is not present in my folder, not sure from where this is showing up.

Comment: Wild guess: Maybe a ZIP file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it is a security issue.. Check the read rights of the sql running service , on that folder.
Another possible cause , could be a mapped folder. If your files are located in a mapped folder, and you restarted your pc , the connection is lost, so you should declare again the path .